# iOS - UUID generation throwing a strange exception

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uuid

I am trying to use https://github.com/gekitz/UIDevice-with-UniqueIdentifier-for-iOS-5 to generate a global identifier. When I try the sample in git it works fine and displays an identifier correctly. But when I try to incorporate the files into a new project it does not work!

I have included -

```
#import "UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.h"
```

in my SampleAppDelegate.m, copy pasted all files in the project, and am using

```
NSString *di = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier];
```

in the init method. I put a breakpoint on the first line of uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier method, but it is never reached! Am I missing something?

**EDIT:**

Exception -

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDevice uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68170c0'
```

Comment: If you log the string di returned from the function, what do you get?

Comment: the call does not reach the function as I mentioned! I put a breakpoint on the first line of uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier and it never reached there.

Comment: Yes, but if you put `NSLog(@"di: %@", di);` on the next line below the one above, what gets logged to the console?

Comment: nothing. since the exception is at NSString *di = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier]; itself

Comment: Ah, I see. The exception might be nice to see.

Comment: it does not reach the next line. gives a SIGABRT at that line itself.

Comment: its just an "unrecognized selector sent to instance"

Comment: The "unrecognized selector sent to instance" message will also tell you the name of the selector and the class that it was called on.

Comment: added the complete exception in the Edit.

Comment: #import "UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.h"
#import "NSString+MD5Addition.h"
NSString *di = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueDeviceIdentifier]; **Did you add NSString+MD5Addition.h file as well to your project** **Check in your target compiled source**

Comment: It is not recognizing the uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier method so somehow that file has not been added to the project correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like `UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.m` is not being compiled. To check / add it:

1. Click on the project in the navigator on the left in Xcode.
2. Select the app target.
3. Select the 'Build Phases' tab.
4. Open up 'Compile Sources'.
5. Check that `UIDevice+IdentifierAddition.m` is in there. If not, then click the '+', select it and click add.

The exception points to this as the fix because it's saying that there is no method on `UIDevice` called `uniqueGlobalDeviceIdentifier`, which is added by the category.