# Bridging an ObjC project with the SalesForce SDK causes a crash due to inability to find a category in the SF SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, salesforce, bridging-header

I have an iOS project called Core.proj that includes the SalesForce SDK and it is written in Objective-C. This project utilises the SF SDK and links the binary to the SF libraries. It does a bunch of stuff to help manage my implementation of SF. It is included in all my other Obj-C projects and it works absolutely fine within them.

This is the first time I am using this project with Swift (2.1). I am using iOS 9 with Xcode 7.1.1. I added the Core.xcodeproj into my Swift project. I then created an ObjC file. Xcode then asks if I want to create a bridging header. I do. I have created a bridging header called Swift-Bridging-Header.h. This enables me to access the files in Core.xcodeproj via the bridging header. For example, I can access my own version of the Salesforce Authentication Manager from the bridging header.

In my app delegate, I want to now kick off OAuth (I'm keeping this minimal here):

```
    let sharedManager = MyAuthenticationManager.sharedManager()

    let successBlock: OAuthFlowSuccessCallbackBlock = { sfAuthInfo in }

    let failureBlock: OAuthFlowFailureCallbackBlock = { sfAuthInfo in }

    sharedManager.loginWithCompletion(successBlock, failure: failureBlock)
```

Full disclosure: each block that you see here takes the SFOAuthInfo object as an argument. In order to get Swift to read this block, I had to add SFOAuthInfo.h into the copy files.

Now this all compiles fine but when I tap to login and execute the above code, I get the following error:

```
    2015-12-04 11:53:54.879 MyApp[19108:3494140] -[UIDevice    macaddress]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcfb4903230
2015-12-04 11:53:54.890 MyApp[19108:3494140] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIDevice macaddress]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fcfb4903230'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d6adf65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f624deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d6b658d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d603f7a ___forwarding___ + 970
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d603b28 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   MyApp                  0x000000010c869317 -[SFOAuthCredentials keyMacForService:] + 84
    6   MyApp                  0x000000010c8696b8 -[SFOAuthCredentials updateTokenEncryption] + 210
    7   MyApp                  0x000000010c8673ee -[SFOAuthCredentials initWithIdentifier:clientId:encrypted:] + 211
    8   MyApp                  0x000000010c84102c -[SFUserAccount initWithIdentifier:] + 197
    9   MyApp                  0x000000010c85f32d -[SFUserAccountManager createUserAccount] + 91
    10  MyApp                  0x000000010c831b41 -[SFAuthenticationManager loginWithCompletion:failure:account:] + 284
    11  MyApp                  0x000000010c831a0b -[SFAuthenticationManager loginWithCompletion:failure:] + 53
    12  MyApp                  0x000000010c60440c -[MyAuthenticationManager loginWithCompletion:failure:] + 124
    13  MyApp                  0x000000010c5dc58f _TFC18MyApp11AppDelegate5loginfS0_FT_T_ + 911
    14  MyApp                  0x000000010c5dfdc4 _TFC18MyApp25LandingPageViewController17loginButtonTappedfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 68
    15  MyApp                  0x000000010c5dfe16 _TToFC18MyApp25LandingPageViewController17loginButtonTappedfS0_FPSs9AnyObject_T_ + 54
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010e1af1fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010e313504 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010e3137d0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    19  UIKit                               0x000000010e312906 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    20  UIKit                               0x000000010e219aa3 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010e21a691 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    22  UIKit                               0x000000010e1cc752 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    23  UIKit                               0x000000010e1a7fcc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5da0a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5cffcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5cf483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010d5cee98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000113e46ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    29  UIKit                               0x000000010e1ad676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    30  MyApp                  0x000000010c5ddd8d main + 109
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x00000001107a592d start + 1
    32  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

The SF SDK has a category called UIDevice+SFHardware.h. Within this category there is a method called 'macaddress'. So clearly it is not correctly reading this category. But why? As you can see from the stack trace it is reading the other files in the SF SDK correctly.

I tried a number of things to get this to work. For example, this: [iOS - UUID generation throwing a strange exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9897162/ios-uuid-generation-throwing-a-strange-exception) but with UIDevice+SFHardware.h. I tried this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000009CBvIAM. I completely rebuilt the project again to check my working.

I shouldn't need to add this file into my bridge as this UIDevice+SFHardware.h is only ever accessed from SF SDK which sits within an ObjC project.

I must have done something wrong though. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this was a combination of things. Firstly, I was missing the -ObjC linker flag in BOTH the Swift project and the Objc project. Thanks DarthVadar123451 for pointing that out. But I also realised I was missing two libraries: libz.dylib and libxml2.dylib. Once added, everything worked. I hope that helps anyone running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this issue.

In your Project > Build Settings > Other Linker Flags add:
-ObjC
-all_load

My SalesforceSDK is in my Pod project. If you're doing the same, set those flags in your SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS project. If not, wherever the Salesforce SDK is getting compiled.